# Redux Toolkit. Minimze code duplication on createSlice

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to wrap my head around a way to minimize duplicated code.

I have a slice that will store an array of objects with the below interface type.

```
interface SomeSliceType {
  id: number;
  sliceObjectA: SliceObjectA;
  sliceObjectB: SliceObjectB;
  sliceObjectC: SliceObjectC[];
  sliceObjectD: unknown;
}
```

Right now we only have sliceObjectA and sliceObjectB. But it's going to have at least two more objects, and it might grow even more.

What would be a good approach to avoid having 12 +  reducers with duplicated code, when it's basically the same three actions just storing 4 different types.

- Add a complete array to sliceObjectX where id = n
- add one to sliceObjectX  where id = n
- remove one from sliceObjectX  where id = n
  The slice reducers look something like this,

```
export const someSlice = createSlice({
  name: "someSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addSomeSlice: (state, action: PayloadAction<SomeSliceType>) => {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    setSliceObjectA: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<{ id: number; sliceObjectA: SliceObjectA[] }>
    ) => {
      const myRow = state.find((row) => row.id === action.payload.id);
      if (myRow) {
        myRow.sliceObjectA = action.payload.sliceObjectA;
      }
    },
    addToSliceObjectA: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<{ id: number; sliceObjectA: SliceObjectA }>
    ) => {
      const myRow = state.find((row) => row.id === action.payload.id);
      if (myRow) {
        myRow.sliceObjectA?.push(action.payload.sliceObjectA);
      }
    },
    removeFromSliceObjectA: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<{ id: number; sliceObjectA: SliceObjectA }>
    ) => {
      const myRow = state.find((row) => row.id === action.payload.id);
      if (myRow) {
        const newSliceObjectA = myRow.sliceObjectA?.filter(
          (row) => row.id !== action.payload.sliceObjectA.id
        );
        myRow.sliceObjectA = newSliceObjectA;
      }
    },
    // repeat here for SliceObject B, etc.. 
  },
});
```